# Retrofit Android 2.1 API Level 7 Support

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Does Retrofit support android 2.1? I try disable keep alive on Application class
But still showing me ClassNotFound of ConnectionPool.
I am running OK AVD api 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mistakenly broke support for Android < 2.3 in OkHttp 1.5. We're going to put out an OkHttp 1.5.1 on March 11 or 12 that should fix the problem. In the interim, OkHttp 1.3 should work on Android 2.1.